# Find sequence of data in excel using java

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel with some data i need to find the sequence of data entered in the excel,

For ex:- 
    A1  CaseId      A2  1.1
B1  Accept      B2
C1  LoginID     C2  newUser
D1  Password    D2  newUser@123
E1  LoginBtn    E2
F1  CollnApp    F2
G1  ScreenShot  G2  No
H1  HighLight   H2  Yes
I1  Description I2  LoginTC
J1  Execute     J2  Yes

where A1....J2 means the excel cells

(Please note that i do not want to add another row stating sequence and then reading it into a map and execute )

Thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you convert it into a csv.. it would be much easier to parse

Comment: can you please let me know how would i be getting the sequence of data in csv ?

Comment: ok, goto file and click on save as.. in options click as csv and it will be done.. just google it if my instructions arent clear

Comment: Sheyas i do know how to convert an xls file to csv, what i meant was how to get sequence of data entered in different columns of excel/csv

Comment: csv are comma separated, you need to read line by line.. after you read every line you need to separate that string using split method.. see the answer for the more code

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do, to read csv contents:

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String[] parameters;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.csv"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);//this is just for your knowing purpose that lines are being read
                parameters = sCurrentLine.split(",");
                //now here you do what ever you want to do with the data
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```